# Python и мистическое исчезновение данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dict

Есть код, который по логам отрисовывает график.
Но временами этот код падает, с ошибкой: `не найдена вершина workstation c именем 'ИМЯ'`.

Код добавления workstation в график:

```
def add_workstation(self, workstation, color=None):
    workstation.users = []
    node = WorkstationNode(workstation, depth=1, color=color)
    self.add_node(node)

    self.workstations[node.name] = node # !!!
    return node
```

Код добавления узла в график

```
def add_node(self, node):
    node.parent = self
    self.nodes[node.name] = node # !!!
```

Добавление нового workstation в итоге происходит как в словарь workstations, так и в словарь nodes абсолютно одинаковым способом. Это единственное место, где workstations и nodes используются не на чтение.

При этом в дампе переменных, когда возникает ошибка не все workstation присутствуют в nodes
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для работы используется Python3, Django 2.2 и Apache2.

Проблема решается через рестарт Apache. При этом первые два-три графика, которые открою сгенерируются без ошибок (даже те, что до рестарта с ошибками). Последующие почти все графики упадут в эту ошибку.

В чём может быть причина такого странного поведения?

---

Comment: похоже на утечку памяти или какого то другого ресурса.

Comment: Нет ли в коде места, где add_node вызывается сам по себе, в обход add_workstation ?

Comment: @Xander Есть, например, в add_user. Это нормально, что в nodes записей больше, чем workstations. Но при этом все записи из workstations должны быть в nodes.

Comment: @KoVadim утечка памяти происходит наоборот из-за излишества данных, которые не очищаются. А тут нехватка данных. При этом при утечке памяти, когда лимит выделяемой памяти закончится, процесс будет убит. Так что утечка памяти не может стать причиной исчезновения данных.
Тут больше похоже на вопрос к Apache. Т.к. его перезагрузка решает проблему на несколько запусков графа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в объявлении переменных `workstations` и `nodes`. Оба этих словаря должны были объявляться внутри `__init__`. **Объявляйте переменные (а особенно ссылочные) уникальные для каждого экземпляра класса и не зависимые от самого класса только через `__init__`**

```
class Sankey:

    node_cls = SankeyNode
    link_cls = SankeyLink
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = {}
        self.links = []
```

## Проблемное объявление

```
class UATSankey(Sankey):
    
    users           = {}
    workstations    = {}
```

## Правильное объявление

```
class UATSankey(Sankey):
    
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.users          = {}
        self.workstations   = {}
```

Тем самым для объекта `sankey = UATSankey()` `nodes` являлся частью самого объекта (и работает подобно локальной переменной), а `workstations` является частью класса (и работает как глобальная переменная).

Что это значит. Если я рисую первый график, то `nodes` и `workstations` пустые, всё работает, и график отрисовывается нормально. Если график рисуется второй раз, то `nodes` пустой (т.к. он был частью объекта), а `workstations` уже не пустой (т.к. он часть класса). Перед созданием нового `WorkstationNode` проверяется его существование через `workstations`, и если он есть, то новый экземпляр не создаётся. Поэтому запись в `workstations` не производится, там хранится запись из старого графика. Запись в `nodes` также не производится, он остаётся пустым, т.к. был очищен для нового графика в отличие от `workstations`.

*Почему график рисовался 2-3 раза нормально?* В настройках Apache включено 3 процесса wsgi. Происходила балансировка на разные процессы, где переменные `nodes` и `workstations` всё ещё были пустыми.

*Почему перезапуск Apache решал проблему?* Так как при перезапуске убивались старые процессы wsgi и порождались новые, с чистыми `nodes` и `workstations`.